# how color only one line in textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need color the selected row with jquery. Suppose I have a textarea which there are into a line.  I need tp color the line that was clicked when the user click on the textarea. So I use this code:

```
$(document).on("mouseup", '#scroll_bar', function(eventData) {
        console.log("DELLLLLLLLL");
        var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop()
        var lineHeight = $(this).css("line-height");
        lineHeight = parseInt(lineHeight.substring(0, lineHeight.length - 2));

        var line = Math.floor((eventData.offsetY + scrollPosition) / lineHeight);

        alert($(this).val().split("\n")[line]);
    });
```

But I find the line that the user clicked but I don't how selected with a color like orange. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can't color parts of a textarea only, it's all or nothing.

Comment: @adeneo you are correct, but what about a background which doesn't cover the entire textarea, e.g. using a background image or linear-gradient? Think more creative ;-) (like in the answer of daanvanham)

Comment: @RogierSpieker - that's actually quite nifty, and an upvote from me, but you still can't color a line in a textarea, but I'll admit that linear backgrounds is trickery that gives the same impression.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to color one (or more) line(s) of the textarea with a background-image.

Here you have an example how you can do it with linear-gradient as background-image.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0px, red 0px, red 22px, #fff 22px);
background-position: 20px;
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/c6hzg08d/)

Comment: I tried to do it, but it doesn't scroll when you scroll textarea.